# Sessions and authentication killed in Laravel 5, running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, vps, session

I've a VPS Provided from Amazon web services , and I've deployed more than 6 "laravel" projects which is worked perfectly , but I've same issue for 3 projects , which is sessions and authentication not working at all , although it success and redirect but with a killed session ,, i tried to deploy these project on other shared hosting and it worked perfectly , i want to know the problem that cause this failure on my AWS

Comment: I believe more informationj is needed. What exactly are you trying to do, and what the error message you receive?

Comment: i've deployed which is working prefeclty on localhost , after deploying on aws , authentication is not working "although check is successfully" but after refresh it redirect with a session killed